# AS3 How to get a movieclip to resize on mouseover?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseover

I am working on a menu within a game in CS6/AS3.

There are a few classic button symbols that refer to another page, there is a music toggle button(mc) and then there is a credits button, which is actually a movieclip. This mc shows a text on mouseclick. The text is also an mc.

I would like to match this mc to the other buttons, which grow on mouseover. Now considering the mc works with the 'visible' command, I don't want to use different frames for the mouseover effect. I was thinking to use a rescaling command, but I can't get it to work. Anyone an idea? Thanks.

So all of this inside the menu movieclip:

```
txtCredits.visible = false
btnCredits.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, ovrCredits);
btnCredits.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, outCredits);
btnCredits.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dwnCredits);

function ovrCredits(event:MouseEvent):void{
    btnCredits.scale = 2;
}
function outCredits(event:MouseEvent):void{
    btnCredits.scale = 1;
}

function dwnCredits(event:MouseEvent):void{

if(txtCredits.visible){
    txtCredits.visible = false;
    }
    else{
    txtCredits.visible = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: `btnCredits.scaleX = btnCredits.scaleY = 2;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that a [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) (the MovieClip in your case) doesn't have a property called "scale". I think that you mean [`DisplayObject.scaleX`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scaleX) and [`DisplayObject.scaleY`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scaleY) :

```
mc.scaleX = 1.2;
mc.scaleY = 1.2;
```

which are equivalent to :

```
mc.width *= 1.2;
mc.height *= 1.2;
```

or

```
mc.width += mc.width * 0.2;
mc.height += mc.height * 0.2;
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: @Ribbon37 You are welcome. You can select my answer as accepted if it was what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, I couldn't find it before. Done.